# Change default HTML tag inside a widget in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, widget

I'm a newbie in PHP and Wordpress. Currently I have a footer widget with the code as follows.

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer col-sm-12">
                <div class="smicon-box icon-left">
                    <div class="boxes-icon">
                        <span class="inner-icon">
                          <span class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I need to change the `i` tag here to `em` tag. Any help to fix this requirement is appreciated.

Comment: did you create custom widget  for footer?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to change the `i` - this is how Font Awesome icons are displayed.

Yes, `i` used to be used to mean *italic*, and in that circumstance changing it to `em` would be entirely correct, but that's not its usage here so leave it alone or your icons won't be displayed.

Comment: In order to make site ADA compliant, this is one of the known issues to be fixed. Otherwise I would have left this as it is, but here I have to change it to <i> or <strong> as per the recommendations in achecker.

Comment: Well, all I can do is reiterate what I said - `<i>` is not being used for _italics_ markup. If you change that line to read `<em class="fa fa-calendar"></em>` you will find that you no-longer have a calendar icon displayed in your footer. In order to make that change you will need to make sure you are using a Child Theme (see Codex instructions [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for info on how to do that), then copy the file called `footer.php` from your parent theme to your child theme and make the change there.